# Inject member variable before injection constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection

In the injection constructor of a class, I have to call the super constructor with proper parameters. The super should call a method of the child class by multimorphism (I have multiple subclasses from the same parent implementing the same method).
The problem is that methods in the child classes depend on having member variables already injected. The Subclasses in my case depend on multiple variables of different types.
Moreover, the parent class is a native one in some library that I cannot change.
See the following exemplary, very simplified, code:

```
public class A {

    @Inject
    public A(SomeType t)
    {
        workon(t1);
    }
}


public class B extends A{

    @Inject
    private MemberType mt;

    @Inject
    public B(SomeType t)
    {
        super(t)
    }

    public void workOn(SomeType t)
    {
        // mt is not set yet since this method
        // is called from the super constructor!
        mt.setT(t);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inject the member variable before calling the inherited method other than initializing it manually?

Comment: in order to construct an instance of B, you need the same instance. well, it smells like a design flaw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should NOT call overridable methods from a constructor. There are many articles explaining this, for example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=215

Answer (score 1):

Inject an instance of `MemberType` into the constructor of `A` explicitly:

```
interface Workon {
    public void workon(SomeType t);
}

class MemberType implements Workon {
    public void workon(SomeType t) {
        this.setT(t);        
    }
}

class A {
    @Inject 
    public A(SomeType t, Workon w) {
        w.workon(t);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private final MemberType mt;

    @Inject 
    public B(SomeType t, MemberType mt) {
        super(t, mt);
        this.mt = mt;
    }
}
```

Generally, constructor injection is your friend. If a class needs a *thing*, it's often best to make it explicitly require *thing* in the constructor, because then you know for sure it's ready when it's needed. This will sometimes require coming up with new types of things.

In this case, the specific behavior of the `workon` method changes the behavior of the constructor of `A`; i.e. it's a parameter of the behavior of the constructor of `A`, so just make it an actual parameter.

---

If you can't change the constructor of `A`, and assuming that `A` doesn't explicitly depend on the result of `workon`, you could also call the actual implementation of `workon()` from `B` when it's possible:

```
class B extends A {
    SomeType t;
    MemberType t;

    public B (SomeType t) {
        super(t);
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void workon(SomeType t) {
        // do nothing here
    }

    // should get called after the object is fully constructed
    @Inject
    public void setMt(MemberType mt) {
        this.mt = mt;
        // what workon() did
        mt.setT(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is surely one solution, but the subclasses I have have different requirements and I can't change the super constructor (The above example is just a simplification)

Comment: Not being able to change an (arguably broken) constructor is a pretty significant requirement, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: @AHH - gave it another go, whether the second solution works still might depend on some specifics of your case that were omitted though.